# Semaphore post to greater than one

Tags: c++, multithreading, semaphore

How can I make the value of Semaphore greater than one. I am trying to write a program that initiates two threads and have the two threads run concurrently after a certain condition is met. 
The program is trying to copy two arrays (b1 and b2) of size 5 to a 10*10 array. Every iteration the values of b1 are copied to x[0][i] to x[4][i] and the values of b2 are copied to x[5][i] to x[9][i] (where i is the iteration index).

the results at the end should look like:

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11
3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12
4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13
5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14
6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15
7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16
8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
```

I tried to the following code:

Driver.cpp

```
#include <sys/types.h>  /* Primitive System Data Types */ 
#include <errno.h>      /* Errors                      */
#include <stdio.h>      /* Input/Output                */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* General Utilities           */
#include <thread>       /* C++11 Threads               */
#include <string.h>     /* String handling             */
#include <semaphore.h>  /* Semaphore                   */
#include <vector>       /* Vector                      */
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "handler.h"
using namespace std;

sem_t Sema1;
sem_t Sema2;
int ThreadsNumber = 2; /* shared variable */
int counter;
vector<std::thread> threadList;

int main()
{

int x[10][10];
int b1[5];
int b2[5];
sem_init(&Sema1, 0, 2);      /* initialize Sema1 to Lock - binary     semaphore */
sem_init(&Sema2, 0, 1);      /* initialize Sema2 to UnLock - binary semaphore */

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sem_wait(&Sema2);
    counter = ThreadsNumber;
    // Update the matrix
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        b1[j] = j + i;
        b2[j] = j + i + 5;
    }

sem_init(&Sema1, 0, 2);

        if (i == 0)
        {
        // Create the threads during the first interations  
        threadList.push_back(std::thread(handler, x, b1, 0, 0));
        threadList.push_back(std::thread(handler, x, b2, 5, 1));
        }


    // Kill all threads in the last iteration 
        if (i == 9)
    {
        for (auto& threadID : threadList){
            threadID.join();
        }
    }


}


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        cout << left << setw(4) << x[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

sem_destroy(&Sema1); /* destroy semaphore */

/* exit */
return 0;
} /* main() */
```

handler.cpp

```
#include "handler.h"
void handler(int x[10][10], int b[], int start, int id)
{
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sem_wait(&Sema1);       /* down semaphore */
    for (int j = start; j < 5 + start; j++)
    {
        x[i][j] = b[j - start];
    }

/*      printf("Thread %d: Waiting to print results...\n", id);

    for (int j = start; j < 5 + start; j++)
    {
        printf("x[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, x[i][j]);
    }
*/
    counter--;
    cout << counter << endl;
    if (counter == 0)
    {
        sem_post(&Sema2);
    }
    /* END CRITICAL REGION */

}
}
```

handler.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <semaphore.h>
using namespace std;

extern sem_t Sema1;
extern sem_t Sema2;
extern int ThreadsNumber;
extern int counter;


/* prototype for thread routine */
void handler(int x[10][10], int b[], int start, int id);
```

but it only did not work well and I did not get the expected results. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: [sem_init()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_init.3.html) well allows to initialize the semaphore with a value different from `0`. It's unclear what actually didn't _work well_ with your usage. You'll have to call `sem_wait()` at least two times, to unlock the semaphore from that initial situation.

Comment: Please see the edited question above

Comment: You didn't really add the crucial information: _What actually **didn't work well** with your usage?_

Comment: one of the threads run when setting the semaphore to 2 and the other one does not work. Hence the values of the x array are not as expected.

Comment: As you've been asking for alternative ways, I'd recommend you to have a look at [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable), which looks coming closest for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After through out study to semaphore I was able to fix the above code as follow:

driver.cpp

```
#include <sys/types.h>  /* Primitive System Data Types */ 
#include <errno.h>      /* Errors                      */
#include <stdio.h>      /* Input/Output                */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* General Utilities           */
#include <thread>       /* C++11 Threads               */
#include <string.h>     /* String handling             */
#include <semaphore.h>  /* Semaphore                   */
#include <vector>       /* Vector                      */
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "handler.h"
using namespace std;
sem_t Sema1;
sem_t Sema2;
int ThreadsNumber = 2; /* shared variable */
int counter;
vector<std::thread> threadList;

int main()
{

int x[10][10];
int b1[5];
int b2[5];
sem_init(&Sema1, 0, 0);      /* initialize Sema1 to Lock - binary semaphore */
sem_init(&Sema2, 0, 2);      /* initialize Sema2 to UnLock - binary semaphore */
// Create the threads during the first interations  
threadList.push_back(std::thread(handler, x, b1, 0, 0));
threadList.push_back(std::thread(handler, x, b2, 5, 1));

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sem_wait(&Sema2);
    sem_wait(&Sema2);
    //counter = ThreadsNumber;
    // Update the matrix
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        b1[j] = j + i;
        b2[j] = j + i + 5;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ThreadsNumber; i++)
    {
        sem_post(&Sema1);
    }
}

// Kill all threads in the last iteration 
for (auto& threadID : threadList){
    threadID.join();
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        cout << left << setw(4) << x[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

sem_destroy(&Sema1); /* destroy semaphore */

/* exit */
return 0;
} /* main() */
```

handler.cpp

```
#include "handler.h"
void handler(int x[10][10], int b[], int start, int id)
{
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sem_wait(&Sema1);       /* down semaphore */

    for (int j = start; j < 5 + start; j++)
    {
        x[i][j] = b[j - start];
    }

        sem_post(&Sema2);

    /* END CRITICAL REGION */

}
}
```

driver.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <semaphore.h>
using namespace std;
extern sem_t Sema1;
extern sem_t Sema2;
extern int ThreadsNumber;
/* prototype for thread routine */
void handler(int x[10][10], int b[], int start, int id);
```